# How to access each element of a 3d matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, 3d

So I have a 3d matrix:

```
[[ 0.99742808 0.01090133 0.07084053] 
[-0.00373406 0.99492706 -0.10052965] 
[-0.07157707 0.10000657 0.99240889]]
```

and I would like to make a function to calculate the rotation angle of this, however, how can I just get a11 or a12, etc. `zip(*matrix)` works on a 2d array, but this is a 3d array. Since I am working with 4 more matrices, I don't want to type in the number for the calculation each time. Is there a simpler way?

Using this function I calculated the rotation matrix:

```
def rotation_matrix(a,b):
    v = np.cross(a, b)
    sine = np.linalg.norm(v)
    cos = np.dot(a, b) 
    vx = np.array([[0, -v[2], v[1]], [v[2], 0, -v[0]], [-v[1], v[0],0]])
    R = np.eye(3) + vx + (np.dot(vx,vx) * (1-cos)/(sine**2) )
    print(R)
```

run this:

```
matrix = rotation_matrix(vector_1, vector_2)
```

where:

```
vector_1: (0.04105606809655358, 0.04476372266923052, 0.9981535996054132) 
vector_2: (0.11214819423654286, -0.05596069534201273, 0.9921145010059682)
```

my output: R:

```
[[ 0.99742808 0.01090133 0.07084053] 
[-0.00373406 0.99492706 -0.10052965] 
[-0.07157707 0.10000657 0.99240889]]
```

Now to find the euler's angles:

```
angle_x = math.atan2(r32,r33 )
angle_y = math.atan2(-(r31), np.sqrt(r32**2 +r33**2))
angle_z = math.atan2(r21,r11)
```

I put in the values manually, and got:

```
θ_x = 0.10043249283304505 
θ_y = 0.07163832967532544 
θ_z = -0.003743670977871371
```

So I just want to know how to call r32 r31 from the matrix.

Comment: Please enclose the matrix data as code not picture as well as expected output to ensure problem can be reproduced by others.

Comment: [[ 0.99742808  0.01090133  0.07084053]
 [-0.00373406  0.99492706 -0.10052965]
 [-0.07157707  0.10000657  0.99240889]]

Comment: What is the expected output? How to calculate the transformation? Elaborate more to make question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so firstly, the data you have given is a **2D** array and **not a 3D array**.

Here is the distinction:

one dimensional array

```py
    array = [0,1,2,9,6,5,8]
```

The array at index 1 has the value 1. The array at index 3 has value 9. If you want to update the 3rd value to 8 in the array, you should do

```py
    array[2] = 8
```

A two-dimensional array is simply an array of arrays. So, you have to give two arguments to access a single value.

```py
    two_dim_array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

If you want to update the 'second' value, you have to do

```
    two_dim_array[0][1] = 'something'
```

That is because `two_dim_array[0]` is a one-dimensional array, and you still have to specify an index to access a value.

From now on, you can keep going deeper with the same reasoning. As any further dimension is another level in the list. So a three dimensional array would be :

```
    3d_array = 
    [
        [
            [1,2,3,4],
            [5,6,7,8]
        ],
        [
            [9,10,11,12],
            [13,14,15,16]
        ]
    ]
```

Now to access a value you have to give .. 3 parameters. Because

```
    3d_array[0] // is a two-dim array
    3d_array[0][1] // is a one-dim array
    3d_array[0][1][0] // is a value
```

So if you have to call each element you can use nested for loops

```py
   for i in range(a): #a is number of sheets
       for j in range(b): #number of rows
            for k in range(c): #number of columns
                print(a[i][j][k])
```